# Flutter Fake Errors

Tags: flutter, dart

I update my flutter to the latest version today. When I use `flutter run` it outputs every previous error that occurred in that specific device (even if they have been fixed) and then it continues to build normally. The build concludes successfully and the app doesn't output any error after that.

I created an error on purpose, and every time I use `flutter run` it outputs even when I have removed it. When the build concludes the app runs normally and no error shows up. If I switch devices no error shows up during `flutter run` but when I create one and then undo it, it acts the same.

I tried this both on android studio and vs code the behavior was the same.

Has anyone else faced this?

----Edit----

I tried downloading the latest version with no change. It doesn't happen only with errors but with print functions as well.

----Edit----

A [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46948) issue page facing the same problem.

My flutter doctor

> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows
> [Version 10.0.18363.535], locale el-GR)
> • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at E:\Chris\Documents\Flutter
> • Framework revision 27321ebbad (2 days ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
> • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
> • Dart version 2.7.0

Comment: I'm also on `Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5` but don't have that error, did you try running `flutter clean`?

Comment: yeah, didn't work. I am downloading the version from the site, to check if something went horibly wrong during the update

Comment: I have this issue also, but only on my Windows 10 PC, not on my Mac. It is not bothering me, I can develop and fully test normally, even tho the error logs appear for no reason.

Comment: perhaps you could go to the master channel and see if they've put in a fix.  Also, you tried: flutter clean -> flutter pub cache repair, yes?